# How to solve 'rsync' errors?

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, raspberry-pi, qt, cross-compilation

I have been trying to cross-compile Raspberry Pi applications from Ubuntu 18.04.3 to the Raspberry Pi 3 with Qt 5.12.5.

The guide I used is from here: https://mechatronicsblog.com/cross-compile-and-deploy-qt-5-12-for-raspberry-pi/

I'm getting rsync errors at step 7, when I enter in the following command into terminal:

`sync -avz qt5pi pi@raspberrypi_ip:/usr/local`

Terminal returns these failures:

```
sending incremental file list
rsync: chgrp "/usr/local/qt5pi" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
qt5pi/
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/usr/local/qt5pi/bin" failed: Permission denied (13)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/usr/local/qt5pi/doc" failed: Permission denied (13)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/usr/local/qt5pi/include" failed: Permission denied (13)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
qt5pi/bin/
qt5pi/doc/
qt5pi/include/
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/usr/local/qt5pi/lib" failed: Permission denied (13)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
qt5pi/lib/
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins" failed: Permission denied (13)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/usr/local/qt5pi/qml" failed: Permission denied (13)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
qt5pi/plugins/
qt5pi/qml/
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/usr/local/qt5pi/translations" failed: Permission denied (13)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
qt5pi/translations/

sent 222,520 bytes  received 1,699 bytes  49,826.44 bytes/sec
total size is 118,523,823  speedup is 528.61
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]
```

What can I do to fix these consistent failures?  Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried:

`sync -avz qt5pi root@raspberrypi_ip:/usr/local`

With no success. Everytime I enter the password to establish a connection with the Pi, it tells me to try again until the connection closes. I have also edited /etc/ssh_config file on the Pi where the Permit Root Login line was changed (PermitRootLogin yes).

In addition, the /etc/sshd_config file was edited in the Pi with a reboot afterwards.  I recently entered the command: `sudo systemctl restard sshd` in the Pi terminal via PuTTY. The Ubuntu Terminal still informs me to try again until when entering the password for the Pi until the connection closes to the raspberry pi.

Comment: Does user `pi@raspberrypi_ip` have write permissions on directory `/usr/local`?  You likely need to be `root@raspberrypi_ip` in order to rsync into that directory.

Comment: @JimL. Thanks for the response, I've also tried doing root@raspberrypi_ip with no success. Everytime I use the password, it tells me to try again until the connection closes. I have also edited /etc/ssh_config where the Permit Root Login line was changed (PermitRootLogin yes).

Comment: If root login doesn't work with `PermitRootLogin yes` then either you forgot to restart `sshd` after making that change, or you have the wrong password.  Please: a) [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/548175/edit) to show the case where you use `root@raspberrypi_ip` in your rsync command line.

Comment: Please add the output from the following to your post: `ssh root@raspberrypi_ip ls -ld /usr/local` and `ssh root@raspberrypi_ip ls -l /usr/local`

Comment: @JimL. Hello, I have added my attempts with root@raspberrypi_ip at the bottom of the post

Comment: The proper file to modify is `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  Please notice the precise path and filename, your post still has it wrong. I suggest you forget about rsync and just try to get to where you can successfully do `ssh root@raspberrypi_ip`. It sounds like that is where your ssh-fu is failing.

Comment: @JimL. Good news.  It seems like this installation of Raspbian didn't have the root password configured yet.  Once I configured it, I was able to everything successfully with root@raspberrypi_ip.  Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome.